# Removing the ib_ipoib driver in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, infiniband

I want to build a my own RDMA driver module which sits on the same layer as that of `ipoib`. My HCA card has `2 ports 0 and 1` and I think the IPoIB driver uses both of these ports as `ib0` and `ib1`.

Since the ipoib driver uses the two ports, I think that my RDMA module could not use those two ports using the kernel **IB access layer**. *So I need to remove the ipoib driver so that those two ports are relased and be available as free*.

Whenever I try to unload or remove `ib_ipoib` driver from the linux kernel using

`rmmod ib_ipoib`

command nothing actually happens and `lsmod` shows that the module `ib_ipoib` still remains.

What should I do to remove this IPoIB driver module OR Removing the
IPoIB driver is not at all necessary ?

Comment: If you want to force the removal of any kernel module use the `rmmod -f` command, this command will remove any modules that were not designed to be removed or are being used.

Comment: What is meant by "not designed to be removed" ? Any modules could be removed, right ?

Comment: open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add at the bottom the following: `blacklist ib_ipoib` and reboot.

Comment: The `ib_core` module is designed to allow multiple kernel module and user-space applications to use InfiniBand devices concurrently. I don't think you need to remove the IPoIB module unless you are writing your own IPoIB driver.